# Understanding setup for doubly linked list in Java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am working on a doubly linked list in Java. So that I can create functions, I'm first working to understand the setup.
I have this code. I have started comments with what each line does. Looking at tutorials and I want to make sure I understand this correctly. I still get a little confused on using classes.

If I create a new node by Node x = new Node();  - I am creating a new node of class Node. So that creates an instance using "static class Node {"
Each Node created contains a int item, Node next, and Node prev, that I will set in my functions. The int item I assume is the contents of the Node.
What does the line "public Node() {}" do?

```
public class MyDeque {

Node first = null; //instance variable, first is of type node and is set to null
Node last = null; //instance variable, last is of type node and is set to null
int N = 0;  //keeping track of number of nodes

static class Node {
    public Node() { }
    public int item; 
    public Node next; //next is of type node
    public Node prev; //prev is of type node
}
```

Comment: it is a public constructor https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html. Anyway you should probably stop what you are doing. Before reading code and trying to figure it out, you should grab a good Java book to grasp language rules.

Comment: If you do have not a good concept of classes and constructors, I will suggest learning Object oriented concepts before Learning data structures.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this setup for Double-Linked-List you need to understand how a constructor works; A constructor is like a method, which is used to initialize properties of a class when the object of this class is initialized in memory for the first time.

Let's take your code for an example, I modified it in a proper way to understand why and how constructors used in Java -

```
public class MyDeque {

Node first;
Node last;    
int N;

public MyDeque(){
  this.first = null;
  this.last = null;
  this.N = 0;
}

static class Node {
    int item; 
    Node next;
    Node prev;
    public Node() {       
       this.next = null;
       this.prev = null;
    }
    public void setItem(int item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public int getItem(){
        return this.item;
    }

    // ... public getters for other items
}
```

As you can see two constructors `public Node(){}` and `public MyDeque(){}` are used to set values for the properties of those objects when they are initialized in memory for the first time.

Later, of course, you can set / unchange / change values of properties using the setter method or using the "." operator but remember constructor will always take place when the objects are initialized or reinitialized in memory for the first time.